# Add semi-transparent button to ListView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, transparent

I have listview control. I need to add semi-transparent button with image to listview. Something like this:

[image]

I found [several](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7977/Transparent-Bitmap-Buttons-with-Alpha-Blended-Regi) [projects](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4390/AlphaBlendTextBox-A-transparent-translucent-textbo) that use semi-transparent buttons on the form. But when I transfer them to the ListView, they do not work.

Necessary to use .net 2.0 framework.

Comment: What do you mean _they do not  work_ ? Also: what do you mean by _transfer them to the ListView_ ? This may seem trivial but it is not: You can move a Control over another or add it to the other Control's Controls collection. (For containers by using the mouse for other like a Listview by setting its parent property) Finally: There is no working semitransparency in Winforms unless you draw it yourself. Anything not owner drawn will only let an initial background shine through but will not live update it..

Comment: 1. "What do you mean they do not work?" - Transparent dont work. 2. I transfered them to the listview two ways: put on the listview and add to Controls collections listview - no one method does not work.

Comment: I suggest not doing it. Transparent Buttons are an abomination. And awfully hard to get really right in Winforms. But first and foremost they are a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some solution.

[Making Transparent Controls - No Flickering](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?aid=26878&av=611567)

I inherit my TransparentToggleButton class from TranspControl class:

```
public class TransparentToggleButton : TranspControl
{
    private Image _normalState;
    private Image _mouseUpState;
    private Image _activateState;
    private bool _state;
    private bool _mouseUnder;
    public event EventHandler StateChanged;

    public bool ToggleState
    {
        get { return _state; }
        set
        {
            _state = value;
            SetImage();
        }
    }

    public void SetImages(Image normalState, Image mouseUpState, Image activateState)
    {
        BackImage = normalState;
        _normalState = normalState;
        _mouseUpState = mouseUpState;
        _activateState = activateState;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseClick(e);
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            _state = !_state;
            if (StateChanged != null)
                StateChanged(this, e);
            SetImage();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
        _mouseUnder = true;
        SetImage();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        _mouseUnder = false;
        SetImage();
    }

    private void SetImage()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_state)
                BackImage = _activateState;
            else
                BackImage = _mouseUnder ? _mouseUpState : _normalState;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Function SetImages loads the 3 images that used for normal state, normal state when cursor over the button, activate state.

Besides need catch [listview scroll event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909462/how-to-make-scroll-event-for-listview) and Invalidate() TransparentToggleButton.